# comment system switching to ajax, so not going to a different page

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I was able to write comment system in python, django. but to make a comment the user has to move to different url. I don't want the users to move to a different page to write,edit,delete comment. I googled and it seems like I have to use ajax but I'm not sure. can someone guide me how to do it?

```
views.py

@login_required
def comment_new(request, post_pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'community/comment_form.html', {
        'form':form,
        })

@login_required
def comment_edit(request, post_pk, pk):
    #post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    if comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect(comment.post)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save()
            return redirect(comment.post)
    else:
        form = CommentForm(instance=comment)
    return render(request, 'community/comment_form.html', {
        'form':form,
        })

@login_required
def comment_delete(request, post_pk, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    if comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect(comment.post)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment.delete()
        return redirect(comment.post)
    return render(request, 'community/comment_confirm_delete.html', {
        'comment':comment,
        })
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_edit', args=[self.post.pk, self.pk])

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_delete', args=[self.post.pk, self.pk])
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='community-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/new',views.comment_new, name='comment_new'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/edit',views.comment_edit, name='comment_edit'),
    path('post/<int:post_pk>/comment/<int:pk>/delete',views.comment_delete, name='comment_delete'),
```

my html

```
<a href="{% url 'comment_new' post.id %}">hello</a> 

  <ul>
    {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
    <li>
      {{comment.message}} by {{comment.author}} at {{comment.created_at}}
      {% if comment.author == request.user %}
      <a href="{{ comment.get_edit_url }} ">
        edit
      </a>
      <a href="{{comment.get_delete_url}}">delete</a>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['message']
```

Comment: It can be clearly achievable with ajax. Please have a look at here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started
Also, you will need to return json object from python, not html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show the html. I'll do the ajax code for you if you do.

First you need to make sure you have jquery in your script. Put this after the head and before the body

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Next you have to call a javascript function via onclick for the AJAX request.

```
   {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}

      <a href=onclick="get_delete({{comment.id}})">delete</a>

    {% endfor %}
```

Here is the javascript function you call:

```
function get_delete(n){

var patch = '{% url "comment_delete" %}'
var post_data = {
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken':"{{ csrf_token }}",
 'iddy':n,}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: patch,
  data:post_data,
  datatype:'json',
success: function(data){
console.log(data)
return
}

})}
```

change your url path to.

```
path('post/commentdelete',views.comment_delete, name='comment_delete')
```

finally, in views

```
def comment_delete(request):
    if request.POST:
        response_json = request.POST
        response_json = json.dumps(response_json)
        data = json.loads(response_json)
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=data['iddy'])
        if comment.author != request.user:
            msg = "you didnt write this comment"
            data = {'msg':msg}
        else:
             comment.delete()
             msg = "deleted"
             data = {'msg':msg}
   return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: ohh that would be amazing!! Ive been going over ajax but it's harder than i expected.

Comment: I need to see the form, too. In the html, that is.

Comment: (FYI: everything here is done extremely backwards. You don't want to be sending ID's through your URL, first of all) But before I fix it up, I need to see where the form is in the html so I know what your fields are named to get the information to send through an AJAX request.

Comment: okay I'll post the whole thing here........hmm I'm still learning. if you can fix or comment how I wouldl be super grateful

Comment: Not forms.py. I need to see the form in the HTML. The input, or textarea, or whatever you have, where the user enters the new comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194300/discussion-between-rosababy-and-jay).

Comment: Hi!!!!! can you please take a look at this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517491/ajax-not-activating-taking-me-to-a-different-page