# ajax not activating, taking me to a different page

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

the code works as I want but it takes me to a different page and have something like {"success": 1, "voteobj": 57}. I was informed ajax is the one for this but I'm not good at it. here's what I have. can someone check where I made an error and what I should do to fix it/?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
        {
    $(".vote_form").submit(function(e) 
        {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var btn = $("button", this);
                var l_id = $(".hidden_id", this).val();
                btn.attr('disabled', true);
                $.post("vote/", $(this).serializeArray(),
                function(data) {
                        if(data["voteobj"]) {
                    btn.text("-");
                        }
                        else {
                    btn.text("+");
                        }
                });
                btn.attr('disabled', false);
        });
        });
</script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form method="post" action="{% url 'vote' %}" class="vote_form">
    <li> [{{ post.votes }}]
        {{post}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" id="id_post" name="post" class="hidden_id" value="{{ post.pk }}" />
        <input type="hidden" id="id_voter" name="voter" class="hidden_id" value="{{ user.pk }}" />
        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>login to vote</p>

        {% elif post.pk not in voted %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary">like</button>
        {% else %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary">dislike</button>
        {% endif %}
            </form>
```

And following is my python code

```
class JSONFormMixin(object):
    def create_response(self, vdict=dict(), valid_form=True):
        response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(vdict), content_type='application/json')
        response.status = 200 if valid_form else 500
        return response

class VoteFormBaseView(FormView):
    form_class = VoteForm

    def create_response(self, vdict=dict(), valid_form=True):
        response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(vdict))
        response.status = 200 if valid_form else 500
        return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=form.data["post"])
        user = self.request.user
        prev_votes = Vote.objects.filter(voter=user, post=post)
        has_voted = (len(prev_votes) > 0)

        ret = {"success": 1}
        if not has_voted:
            # add vote
            v = Vote.objects.create(voter=user, post=post)
            ret["voteobj"] = v.id
        else:
            # delete vote
            prev_votes[0].delete()
            ret["unvoted"] = 1
        return self.create_response(ret, True)


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        ret = {"success": 0, "form_errors": form.errors }
        return self.create_response(ret, False)



urls.py

urlpatterns = [   
    path('vote/', auth(VoteFormView.as_view()), name='vote'),
```

Edit: I followed the instruction on the following web: https://arunrocks.com/building-a-hacker-news-clone-in-django-part-4/

Everything works good but ajax on my side

Edit: So without ajax the url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/community/vote/
With ajax the url is 
/community/post/3/vote/
but it says Not Found: on terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 return self.create_response(ret, True)
```

should be

```
return JsonResponse(safe=False, ret)
```

Sorry, I didn't take my time and answered lazily. Don't change response. Keep that as you have it and do what I just did above.

Should work.

Comment: it goes to a different page /vote as well with the messagee "{\"success\": 1, \"voteobj\": 64}"

Comment: thaty's bc you're not calling it with ajax. You have to use ajax.

Comment: so what's wrong with the ajax? (like I posted in the original question) plz help

Comment: Well, you're not using it. You have to go on youtube and take the time to learn it. It's important when using Django.

Comment: I see can you write one just this time??pleaseee

Comment: I need to see URLs to do the rest.

Comment: hmmm stil not working I'll post the URL and add the bounty to the question if that helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194780/discussion-between-rosababy-and-jay).

Comment: Hello I posted url

Comment: i already edited my answer for you. what I changed should work.

Comment: why is there vote2? can you please check out the link, tutorial i followed??

Comment: or as an alternate solution, i don't mind giving users a new page(the page I can modify so more friendly). right now it just shows {success:1

Comment: vote2 is so you can call an Ajax function/submit form without changing pages,

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="runthis({{post.pk}})">like</button>

function runthis(n){




var patch = '{% url "vote2" %}'

comment = document.getElementById('id_post').value
comment2 = document.getElementById('id_voter').value
info = {"comment":comment, "comment2":"comment2", 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':"{{ csrf_token }}", 'query':n}


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: patch,
  data:info,
    datatype:'json',
   headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },



success: function(data){

console.log('success')
return

}


})
```

add to urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [   
    path('vote/', auth(VoteFormView.as_view()), name='vote'),
    path('vote2/', view.vote2, name='vote2')]
```

then add to  views.

```
def vote2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_json = request.POST
        response_json = json.dumps(response_json)
        data = json.loads(response_json)
        this_is_the_pk = data['query']
        this_is_the_comment = data['comment']
        this_is_the_comment2 = data['comment2']
return JsonResponse(safe=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error that JQuery is not defined, so e.preventDefaults() never runs and you get the standard form submit action. Try including the script tag for pulling in JQuery before this script. Here is how that might look:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
        {
    $(".vote_form").submit(function(e) 
        {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var btn = $("button", this);
                var l_id = $(".hidden_id", this).val();
                btn.attr('disabled', true);
                $.post("vote/", $(this).serializeArray(),
                function(data) {
                        if(data["voteobj"]) {
                    btn.text("-");
                        }
                        else {
                    btn.text("+");
                        }
                });
                btn.attr('disabled', false);
        });
        });
</script>


<form method="post" action="{% url 'vote' %}" class="vote_form">
    <li> [{{ post.votes }}]
        {{post}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" id="id_post" name="post" class="hidden_id" value="{{ post.pk }}" />
        <input type="hidden" id="id_voter" name="voter" class="hidden_id" value="{{ user.pk }}" />
        {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>login to vote</p>

        {% elif post.pk not in voted %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary">like</button>
        {% else %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary">dislike</button>
        {% endif %}
            </form>
```

Also, your HTML seems to be missing a closing `</li>` tag.